# Extract css from matched element

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, firefox-addon, google-chrome-devtools

just wondering if there are a tool who allow select certain element from firefox dev console or chrome dev tools, select some element and extract all the rules associated, even from children ones.

Have a mess cleaning css today!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

[SnappySnippet Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/snappysnippet/blfngdefapoapkcdibbdkigpeaffgcil) is your friend!

Comment: Just for future reference, this requires you replace the HTML with the generated HTML from the extension and uses IDs and does not preserve the original class names.